# JavaScript setTimeout loop only running twice before returning error:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, settimeout

I've been working on a website that processes XML files, And I ran into an issue once I added a bit more processing. The issue I am having is in using setTimeout to give the browser a break to 'breathe' so that it doesn't crash trying to load a bunch of information into innerHTML.  When I load it, it only loops twice, then returns an error of "VM###:1"(### constantly changes).

```
var i = 0;
    process();
    function process(){
        if (i < x.length) {
            var name = $(x[i]).find("Description[DescriptionCode='DEF']").text();
            var ixx = x.length + (20 - (x.length % 20));
            var ix = Math.round((i+10) / 20);
            var type = "";
            var desc = $(x[i]).find("Description[DescriptionCode='DES']").text();
            var lamp = desc;
            var g = 1;
            var id = $(x[i]).find("PartNumber").text();
            var ddId = "D" + id + "D"
            var price = $(x[i]).find("Pricing[PriceType='RMP']").find("Price").text();
            for (n=0;(g == 1) && (n < sType.length); n++) {
                if (desc.indexOf(sType[n].type) > -1) {
                    type = sType[n].type;
                    lamp = lamp.replace(sType[n].type, '');
                    g = 0;
                }
            };
            for (n=0;(g == 1) && (n < sVolume.length); n++) {
                if (desc.indexOf(sVolume[n].vol) > -1) {
                    vol = sVolume[n].vol;
                    lamp = lamp.replace(sVolume[n].vol, ''); 
                    g = 0;
                }
            };
            for (n=0;(g == 1) && (n < sYear.length); n++) {
                if (desc.indexOf(sYear[n].year) > -1) {
                    year = sYear[n].year;
                    lamp = lamp.replace(sYear[n].year, '');
                    g = 0;
                }
            };

            document.getElementById("productDiv").innerHTML += "The stuff I'm processing goes here.";
            i++;
        setTimeout(process(), 1);
        }
    };
```

Comment: It runs only twice, for it's been invoked two times, on line 2 and 3. And remove quotation marks in setTimeout function.

Comment: Changed that, Still doesn't work, just crashes the webpage in the browser instead of executing multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the function `process` inside [`setTimeout`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html):

```
setTimeout(process(), 1);
```

Since `process` returns nothing (as opposed to a function), this will not have any intended effect—let alone the one you're seeking. Moreover, in Chrome, doing so makes the browser unresponsive.

You want to pass a reference to the function to be later executed instead:

```
setTimeout(process, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I was stuck on this for about 3 days, trying about 40 different methods. Thank you!